# How to add mutiple span to <li> javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop, html-lists

I need  populate `<li>` using javascript. I tried this.

ASPX code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12" id="displayDiv" runat="server">
     <ul id="servicesList" runat="server"></ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function PopulateList() {
 var json = "[ { \"Id\":1068, \"Name\":\"Doe\" }, { \"Id\":1070, \"Name\":\"Smith\" },{ \"Id\":1074, \"Name\":\"Jones\" } ]";

    var obj = JSON.parse(json);

    var list = document.getElementById('<%= servicesList.ClientID %>');

    for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj[i].Name));
        li.className = "drag-handle-container";
        li.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-bars'></i>";
        li.setAttribute("data-id", obj[i].Id);
        list.appendChild(li);
    }
}
```

But it's not populated I expected a list with `SPAN` I need this

[image]

```
<ul id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_servicesList">
   <li class="sortable-service-item"><span class="drag-handle-container"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span><span style="display: none;">1068</span><span>Doe</span></li>
   <li class="sortable-service-item"><span class="drag-handle-container"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span><span style="display: none;">1070</span><span>Smith</span></li>
   <li class="sortable-service-item"><span class="drag-handle-container"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span><span style="display: none;">1074</span><span>Jones</span></li>
</ul>
```

According to my code, HTML generating as follows, but I need the above HTML

```
<ul id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ViewProductService_servicesList">
   <li class="drag-handle-container" data-id="1068"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></li>
   <li class="drag-handle-container" data-id="1070"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></li>
   <li class="drag-handle-container" data-id="1074"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></li>
</ul>
```

How to populate above HTML code by using javascript for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requesting a way to achieve your "above" HTML (as you mentioned) but your generated code is vastly different than that. There are "data-ids" , different class-names , etc. Nevertheless , taking for granted that your "above" code is your goal the following 2 ways will produce exactly that. The first way follows your path. Using Native Javascript createElement functions and appending them on DOM elements. The Second way creates a String that represents HTML Code and it inserts it into the DOM creating the whole List.

In both examples i use the [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for the Array loops and the 
[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for the Object loops. I also use [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in those loops which is not necessary though in this case.

**1st Way**

```
let json = "[ { \"Id\":1068, \"Name\":\"Doe\" }, { \"Id\":1070, \"Name\":\"Smith\" },{ \"Id\":1074, \"Name\":\"Jones\" } ]";
let obj = JSON.parse(json);
let list = document.getElementById('servicesList');

obj.forEach((ObjectRow)=>{
 let li = document.createElement("li");
     li.className = "sortable-service-item";

 let Span = document.createElement("span");
     Span.className = "drag-handle-container";
     Span.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-bars'></i>";
     Span.setAttribute("data-id", ObjectRow["Id"]);

 li.appendChild(Span);

 Object.keys(ObjectRow).forEach((key)=>{
   let tempSpan = document.createElement("span");
       tempSpan.innerHTML = ObjectRow[key];
       li.appendChild(tempSpan);
 });

 list.appendChild(li);
});
```

**2nd Way**

```
let json = "[ { \"Id\":1068, \"Name\":\"Doe\" }, { \"Id\":1070, \"Name\":\"Smith\" },{ \"Id\":1074, \"Name\":\"Jones\" } ]";
let obj = JSON.parse(json);
let list = document.getElementById('servicesList');
let myHTML;

obj.forEach((ObjectRow)=>{
 myHTML += "<li class='sortable-service-item'>" + 
            "<span class='drag-handle-container' data-id='"+ObjectRow["Id"]+"'>" + 
             "<i class='fa fa-bars'></i>" + 
            "</span>";

  Object.keys(ObjectRow).forEach((key)=>{
   myHTML += "<span>"+ObjectRow[key]+"</span>";
  });
 myHTML += "</li>";
});

list.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd" , myHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try updated code:

> Change the value inside the for loop as per your requirement.

```js
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.className  = "drag-handle-container";
    var span_1 = document.createElement("span");
    span_1.setAttribute('class', 'drag-handle-container');
    span_1.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>';
    li.appendChild(span_1);
    var span_2 = document.createElement("span");
    span_2.style.display = 'none';
    span_2.innerHTML = '1068';
    li.appendChild(span_2);
    var span_3 = document.createElement("span");
    span_3.innerHTML = 'Doe';
    li.appendChild(span_3);
    console.log(li);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Which shows separate errors in the console. and nothing display
1. `Uncaught TypeError: span_1.addClass is not a function`
2. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` this error shows in this line ` var span_2 = "<span style="display: none;">set dyanmic value</span>";`

Comment: woukd you please Check it now